# In htaccess, how to apply FilesMatch only to files in website root

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In order to avoid access for specific files that are still under construction, I wrote these lines in the website root .htaccess. This worked perfectly:

```
<FilesMatch "login.php|reset.php|raport.php">
AuthUserFile /home/myaccount/public_html/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted area"
Require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

Afterwards, I installed phpBB under /forum. When I try to access its login page... I must authenticate first.

My big question is how to modify the FilesMatch condition in order to apply it for login.php in the website root, but not for login.php in other folders.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If your `FilesMatch` code is in htaccess in your root folder then this will apply to all subfolders unless you create a separate htaccess file. You can solve this by Creating an htaccess file in the subfolder you want to keep away from your parent htaccess with the following content  `RewriteEngine on` .

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SetEnvIf` against the `URI` only form root like this :

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/?(login|reset|raport)\.php" PASS
AuthUserFile /home/myaccount/public_html/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted area"
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
Allow from env=!PASS
```

So , form here `SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/?(login|reset|raport)\.php` you make sure that the `URI` is starting with `login|reset|raport` only and not sub-directory .